# Javascript not changing html background color persistenly

Tags: javascript, html, css

everybody. I'm hoping you can help me here, I'm trying to change the color of the body section of my document through javascript by clicking a button.

There are three buttons, each sets a background color. The problem is: When I click one of 'em, it changes the background color for just a second, then it returns to the originally set color, here's a sample of my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function colorish(my_color){
      if (my_color === 'gray'){
        document.body.style.background = '#CCCCCC';
      }else if (my_color === 'orange'){
        document.body.style.background = '#FF9900';
      }else if (my_color === 'blue'){
        document.body.style.background = '#C1DAD6';
      } else {
        alert('on else');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background: orange;">
  <form>
    <button name="back_color" onclick="colorish('gray')">Gy</button>
    <button name="back_color" onclick="colorish('orange')">Oe</button>
    <button name="back_color" onclick="colorish('blue')">Be</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The script is on a separate file on my environment, but it is the exact same.

If in the script I include:

```
onload = selector();

function selector(){
  var buttons = document.getElementsByName('back_color');

  buttons[0].onclick = colorish('gray');
  buttons[1].onclick = colorish('orange');
  buttons[2].onclick = colorish('blue');
}
```

It just enters every buttons[].on... assignment and leaves the background set to the last assignment, being blue in this case.

I'm not an expert so maybe there's something I'm missing about html with js.

Comment: A tip try using jquery it will make your life a lot easier also provide a fiddle :- www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is the page reloading when you click the button?

Comment: Yes. when you run his code, the page reloads.

Comment: Not that its the problem but your < /body> tag is missing the >

Comment: @Mr.coder I disagree - using jQuery for this type of trivial task is **way** over-kill. Once things get more complicated, OP *may* want to consider switching to jQuery or a similar library.

Comment: @esqew i made that suggestion assuming that the user has much more code than this or planning to use much more code

Comment: Right! I'll fix that tag. I did try that fiddle website but the background wasn't changing either, I assume the obvious, the form tag was the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without declaring a `type` for your buttons, they act as though they are `type="submit"`. Since there's no configured `action` parameter on your `<form>` element, the `action` is the same page on which they are accessed. It's not that the background is only appearing for a split second and then returning to the normal color, the page is reloading and defaulting back to that color just as if you had *just* loaded it.

To stop this behavior, give each of your buttons a `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button" name="back_color" onclick="colorish('gray')">Gy</button>
<button type="button" name="back_color" onclick="colorish('orange')">Oe</button>
<button type="button" name="back_color" onclick="colorish('blue')">Be</button>
```

---

As a side note, if you're not using buttons as part of a form to submit data, you don't need a corresponding `<form>` node - they will function and be standards-compliant all by themselves.

Comment: Wow, quite something I missed right there. Thanks a lot! I'll consider that about the form from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `<form>` tag will fix your problem. Clicking the button submits the form and reloads the page, resetting the page to its original state.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it does indeed fix the code and as far as the code supplied shows he doesn't need a form. Although if it turns out he needs the form then the other answers will be more accurate.

Comment: @user2070057: It is a low quality post. Regardless if it might answer the question, it is of low quality and usefulness. That's what the downvote is signifying.

Comment: I suppose it could be elaborated like the other answer, but in my opinion if it solves the problem and explains why in one sentence it is a complete and acceptable answer.

Comment: @user2070057 Some people down vote for such reasons. While others may or may not agree with that, it's not a completely terrible reason to down vote. *Personally*, I think the answer barely explains things enough to keep me from down voting, but two other people disagree.

Comment: @staticx If you consider this is a low-quality post, you need to state *why.* Ironically your comment is itself very low quality for that reason.

Comment: @EJP: If you want to discuss, go to Meta. I am not going to do it here. It showed up in the low quality queue, I didn't go out looking for this post. It was marked for deletion until it was edited, which brings it out of the delete queue. There is no such thing as a low quality comment and you know that. That's all I am going to say here.